# Write data to excel using Openpyxl

Tags: excel, openpyxl

I have a list `mv = ['200', '200', '4000', '400', '600', '700']` that I want to write to cells `F14` to `F19` in an existing excel table. How do I use `openpyxl` to accomplish this with the list?

So far I have:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook

wb = load_workbook('test.xlsx')
ws = wb['12Channel']


for row in range(14,19):
                for col in range(6):
                    ws.append(mv)
```

The data is not being appended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a proposition with [`openpyxl`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) based on your code :

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook('test.xlsx')
ws = wb['12Channel']

mv = ['200', '200', '4000', '400', '600', '700'] 

for pos, val in enumerate(mv):
    ws.cell(row=pos+14, column=6).value = val # 6 is the position col F
        
wb.save('test.xlsx')
```

##### # Output :

[image]

*NB: Make sure to keep always a backup/copy of your original Excel file before running any kind of python/openpyxl's script.*